# PHP_SELF not working if URL has $_get value?

Tags: php, superglobals

My page url is something like `http://localhost/coursera/instructor/course.php?id=1&name=web%20development&section=overview`

and on that page i have a form like

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">       
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="What will students need to know or do before starting this course? Who is your target student? At the end of my course, students will be able to..." rows="8" required="" name="description"></textarea>
</div>                                   
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-block" name="overview">Save</button>  
</form>
```

But the problem is `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` and `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` are not returning the same url with all the $_Get values.

Anyway to make form return to same page bacause I can't hardcode $_Get Values.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
print_r($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
```

is showing `/coursera/instructor/course.php`
but I want `http://localhost/coursera/instructor/course.php?id=1&name=web%20development&section=overview` **any way to do it?**

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` and see what you can use

Comment: @Federkun I want that when I submit the form i should return to same url but it is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 1:**

> I want that when I submit the form i should return to same url but it
>   is not

You can simply keep the action attribute empty in case you want the form to return to the same page.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

**Update 2:**

While it's working, according to the W3C documentation it's not a valid value.

> The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have
>   a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by
>   spaces.

---

Please notice, PHP_SELF doesn't return the query string (?x=y&z=d).Just the dir and the file name.

**[PHP_SELF](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices)**

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the
>   document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the
>   address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php. The
>   **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor
>   this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it
>   was not available.